# How to watch tasks logs via CLI in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

So I am having a problem: there are no logs displaying in Airflow UI I am currently working with, I don't know the reason, but I've already informed my colleagues about it and they're looking for a solution.

Meanwhile I need to watch logs of certain tasks of my Dag. Is there any way to do it via airflow CLI?
I am using `airflow tasks run` command but it only seems to run tasks, but doesn't show a thing in command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Airflow should store your logs at `$AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/` maybe you'll find them there, if they are still generated.

In the meantime you can use `airflow tasks test <dag_id> <task_id>` this [tests a specific task](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#test_repeat1) and displays the logs in your terminal.